# Applying the Riesz-Thorin Interpolation theorem

Tags: fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis

Consider a linear operator $T$ given by $$T(f)(x)=\int_{Y}K(x,y)f(y)d\nu(y),\qquad x\in X.$$

Let $1\le p_{1}$, $q_{1}\le\infty$, $p_{0}=1$, $q_{1}=\infty$, $\frac{1}{p_{1}}+\frac{1}{p_{1}'}=\infty$ and suppose that $K(x,y)$ satisfies $$\begin{aligned}
A:=\sup_{x\in X}\left(\int_{Y}|K(x,y)|^{p'_{1}}d\nu(y)\right)^{1/p'_{1}}<\infty, \\ B:=\sup_{y\in Y}\left(\int_{X}|K(x,y)|^{q_{0}}d\mu(x)\right)^{1/q_{0}}<\infty.
\end{aligned}$$

I want to show that $T$ extends a bounded operator from $L^{p_{\theta}}(Y)$ into $L^{q_{\theta}}(X)$ for $\frac{1}{p_{\theta}}=1-\theta+\frac{\theta}{p_{1}}$, $q_{\theta}=\frac{q_{0}}{1-\theta}$, $0\le\theta\le 1$, and determine its operator norm.

Of course, I have to utilise the Riez-Thorin interpolation theorem. The second equation gives that $T$ maps $L^{q_{0}}$ to $L^{q_{0}}$ with bound $B$. What about the first equation? I don't really have the intuition for it. If $p_{1}'$ were equal to 1, then it would map $L^{\infty}$ to $L^{\infty}$ with bound $A$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the result often called "Minkowski's Inequality for Integrals".

Say $k_y(x)=K(x,y)$. Then $$Tf=\int_Yk_yf(y)\,d\nu(y),$$so$$||Tf||_{q_0}\le\int_Y||k_y||_{q_0}|f(y)|\,d\nu(y)\le B||f||_1=B||f||_{p_0}.$$

Or if you don't buy that use duality (as in the proof of Minkowski for integrals): Say $g\in L^{q_0'}$. It's enough to show $$\left|\int_XTf(x)g(x)\,d\mu(x)\right|\le B||g||_{q_0'}||f||_1,$$which follows from Fubini.

Comment: I'm slightly confused because you did not use $A$. And this only shows that $T$ maps $L^{q_{0}}$ to $L^{p_{0}}$ with bound $B$, not that I can fully see how you derived that using the Minkowski Inequality.

Comment: No, I showed that $T$ maps $L^{p_0}$ to $L^{q_0}$. Regarding how I showed that, I gave two proofs. Do you know the result known as "minkowski's inequality for integrals"? You say you don't see how I got it using Minkowski. I didn't say I did. Have you tried working out the second proof? (Not that it matters, but I don't see how the second equation shows that $T$ maps $L^{q_0}$ to $L^{q_0}$ as you claim.) Regarding using $A$, the fact that $A$ shows that $T$ maps $L^{p_1}$ to $L^{q_1}=L^\infty$ is just Holder's inequality.

Comment: @user3482534 See for example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_inequality#Minkowski.27s_integral_inequality

Comment: @user3482534 Huh??? I don't know more than one version of Holder. How does it not apply?

Comment: If I'm not wrong, Holder's inequality would yield: $$\|k_{y}f\|_{p_{0}}\le\|k_{y}\|_{p'_{1}}\|f\|_{p_{1}}\le A\|f\|_{p_{1}}$$

Comment: @user3482534 You're wrong. I'm not going to teach you how Holder works - if you can't apply Holder properly there's not much point to any of this. Read Holder again, and see what it says here.

Comment: @user3482534 Hint: Holder says _exactly_ that $|Tf(x)|\le A||f||_{p_1}$. And that says exactly that $||Tf||_{q_1}\le A||f||_{p_1}$, since $q_1=\infty$.

Comment: Thanks for your help. In the end I solved the question using the Marcinkiewicz interpolation theorem.

Comment: @user3482534 Why? We need the estimates at the two endpoints to apply either theorem, and once we have those estimates R-T gives better bounds than M. The advantages to M are that it applies to sublinear operators and that it requires only  weak-type estimates at the endpoints, neither of which matters here...

Comment: Indeed, M did not allow for me to compute the operator norm (which is what I wanted). However, my statement for R-T assumes that $T$ is of strong type $(p,p)$, $(r,r)$ for $1\le p<r\le r$ whereas to use M I only needed that $T$ is of weak type $(p_{1}, q_{1})$ and $(p_{2},q_{2})$ with $1\le p_{1}<p_{2}\le\infty$, $1\le q_{1}<q_{2}\le\infty$ and $p_{1}\le q_{1}$, $p_{2}\le q_{2}$ which is precisely what I had (excluding the bounds).

Comment: Using M I computed that for all $p_{\theta}\in (1,p_{1})$, $T$ is of strong type $(p_{\theta},q_{\theta})$ with $q_{\theta}$ satisfying $$\frac{1}{p_{\theta}}=1-\theta+\frac{\theta}{p_{1}}\qquad\text{and}\qquad q_{\theta}=\frac{q_{0}}{1-\theta}.$$

Comment: @user3482534 But we already _have_ strong type estimates at both endpoints! Oh. You say R-T requires type $(p,p)$ and $(r,r)$. That's not so. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz%E2%80%93Thorin_theorem Whatever source told you it had to be $(p,p)$ is giving you a lame version. (Did that source mean to be stating the general theorem, or was it just giving an example?)

Comment: We had strong type estimates $(1,q_{0})$ and $(p_{1},\infty)$. As far as I'm aware, that is not of the form $(p,p)$ and $(r,r)$ as is required to use R-T (to my understanding).

Comment: @user3482534 Note edit of previous comment - crossed in the mail

Comment: Indeed, you are correct in that I was given a 'lame version' of the theorem. Using the version from Wikipedia, I get the norm estimate $$\|T\|_{L^{p_{\theta}}\to L^{q_{\theta}}}\le\|T\|^{1-\theta}_{L^{1}\to L^{q_{0}}}\|T\|^{\theta}_{L^{p_{1}}\to L^{\infty}}$$